# Auto show print dialog on attachment open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

i have a requirement. on click of a link, an attachment should open up in a new window (using window.open() ). The attachment is ideally a pdf file which resides on web server virtual directory(using IIS 7 for testing).
The input to the pdf attachment is generally a url, such as-

```
http://localhost/attachments/sample.pdf
```

The pdf open up fine but then the page should automatically show the print dialog to the user. The problem is -
1. the attachments are of different sizes.
2. Attachments loading time is variable depending upon its size.

I have tried the following-
1. 'onload' event for body/iframe.
2. jQuery load function to track the loading of the file.
3. $.get operation by enabling CORS on my requested content.
but none of them worked.

here's what i have tried-

```
var dom = window.open( '', '', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
            dom.document.writeln('<html><title>Attachment</title><head>');
            dom.document.writeln('<script type=\'text/javascript\' language=\'javascript\' src=\'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js\'><\/script>');
            dom.document.writeln('<script type=\'text/javascript\' language=\'javascript\'>' );
            dom.document.writeln('$(document).ready(function() {  /*load/get function goes here */});');
            dom.document.writeln('<\/script>')
            dom.document.writeln('</head><body><iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="container" type="application\/pdf" src="http://localhost/attachments/sample.pdf"></iframe></body></html>');
            dom.document.close();
```

Is there any way possible to track the loading of the attachment because i am completely out of options now?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the PDFs themselves, you can [add a print function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_Dev_PrintProduction.75.4.html) to the file itself which would work around the issue of tracking when the iframe is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i can't do that. There can be custom pdf files are well and the no. can reach to thousands or more. So, having the print function to the file is not feasible in this case.